# When running Java jar file my dependency classes aren't found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I currently have a maven project with 1 dependency. When I build it using `mvn package` and run it I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for the classes in my dependency. When I export it as a normal jar in Intellij I still get the same error. I have tried just about everything including setting -cp in the command line. Note that the main class is being found, just not the classes in my dep

### pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>me.jaredstef</groupId>
  <artifactId>hawkeyecountdownbot</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>hawkeyecountdownbot</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
          <version>[4.0,)</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>me.jaredstef.hawkeyecountdownbot.HawkHeart</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**EDIT:** 
Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j/TwitterException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: twitter4j.TwitterException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

Comment: can you show the full message from the console

Comment: Is this the command line showing you this error, or IntelliJ?  Does it work with the command line but not IntelliJ, or vice versa?

Comment: Paste both the POM and the error *here*.  We can't guarantee that Pastebin won't suddenly decide to delete your code.

Comment: When I run the jar made by maven or intellij as `java -jar test.jar` in the terminal

Comment: <version>[4.0,)</version> is that the right syntax?

Comment: @LuisDurazo:  Yeah, that's fine.  I looked into it, and [that's valid syntax.](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html)

Comment: I see you are using Java 8, and I am thinking this could the reason that you get `classNotFound`, `twitter4j` might not work with Java 8. You should try to change to Java 6 or 7 and rebuild the project, see if it works. `ClassnNotFound` error usually caused by compatibility issues.

Comment: @JasonZ:  You're thinking of `UnsupportedClassVersionError`, in which there's a major.minor version conflict (like using Java 7-compatible code in Java 6).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's failing to find a dependent class (twitter4j.TwitterException) which is used in a method signature of a class you are using from your own code.

How do you get this compiled without error?

If that works though it may be an issue of incompatible versions of the twitter4j library to be present: one at compile time (with the TwitterException) and a different one at runtime (without the TwitterException).

This may be caused by your allowing to use "4.0 or higher" in the dependency. It may help to define an exact version there to track this down.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a JAR file with the `-jar` switch, class path defined on the command line (or in environment variables) is ignored.

You will have to add a `Class-Path` manifest attribute that includes the location of your dependencies.

Maven-Jar-Plugin (or more exactly, the [Maven Archiver](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html#class_manifest) configuration) supports this by using the `addClasspath` and `classpathPrefix` options. Note that you still have to ensure that the dependency libs end up in that directory (e. g. by using `maven-assembly-plugin` or by manually copying the dependencies there). Or build a fat jar with maven-assembly-plugin that includes all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to do following:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
          <configuration>
              <descriptorRefs>
                  <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
              <archive>
                  <manifest>
                      <mainClass>Main_Class</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
              </archive>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>single</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>

<finalName>Final_Jar_Name</finalName>
```